# How can I show custom fields value in list manager?

Tags: list-manager

I want to show `custom field value` in the `contacts list of list manager Sitecore 9.3`
[image]

FullName and Number are custom fields

Answer (score 3):

By default, we can only see, *First Name*, *Last Name* and *email* facets values in List Manager view. To extend the contact list view to see custom facets instead of the default ones, you'll need to follow the below steps.
I am assuming you've already created and deployed the custom model that wraps a custom facet, as described in [this](https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2020/08/02/sitecore-xconnect-custom-facets-part-i/) article

1. Add a column for a custom facet to the Contacts table.

- Switch to the *Core* database.
- Add a new ColumnField item under the `/sitecore/client/Applications/List Manager/Lists/Contact list` item.
- Fill out fields, **EmptyText** (sets a default text if a cell does not contain any data. **HeaderText** (a name of the column) and **DataField** (a name of the custom facet, used as a data source).
- Save the changes. The new column then appears in the List Manager app, but without values.

2. Create a custom contacts controller.

- Create your custom **ContactDataModel** to contain all the required facets.
- Data is mapped by the `Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.Repositories.ListSubscriptionsStoreclass`. Create your own class that has a `GetSubscribers` method returning *IEnumerable* of your custom model
- The data is retrieved from `_contactProvider` and converted to the specified model using the MapEntity method. Next, inject the custom mapping logic in the MapEntity method.
- The `_contactProvider.GetFilteredContacts` method returns only three facets (ListSubscriptions, Personal, Emails). So, add the custom ones to the list:
- The default `ListSubscriptionsStore` is used by the `Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.Controllers.ContactsController`  controller. Create your custom controller, which performs the same actions and changes the `GetEntries` method to use the custom `ListSubscriptionsStore` and Change the `RoutePrefix` attribute value of the controller to `sitecore/api/customlists/{listId}/contacts`

3. Create a processor that registers your control:

```
    public class RegisterHttpRoutes
        {
            public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
            {
                GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Configure);
            }
     
            protected void Configure(HttpConfiguration configuration)
            {
                var routes = configuration.Routes;
                routes.MapHttpRoute("CustomContacts", "sitecore/api/customlists/{listId}/contacts", new
                {
                    controller = "CustomContacts",
                    action = "customaction", // Name of the action in ActionName attribute         
                });
            }
```

4. Patch the `RegisterHttpRoutes` processor:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
      <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
          <initialize>
            <processor type="Namespace.RegisterHttpRoutes, AssemblyName"/>
          </initialize>
        </pipelines>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

5. Open Core database in the Content Editor and navigate to the `/sitecore/client/Applications/List Manager/Global Settings/ListTaskPageSettings/ContactsDataSource Parameters` item. Change its URL field to `/sitecore/api/customlists`.

After performing all these steps, you can upload a CSV list containing custom facets.

You can find all the steps in detail and codebase at my blog post: https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/customize-list-manager-part-iii/

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore 10.2 introduced simpler way of extending list manager with custom fields.

You just need to:

- create a new class implementing `IListSubscribersMapper` interface
- implement `MapSubscribers` method:

```
public ContactDataModel MapSubscribers(Contact contact)
{
     var contactDataModel = new ContactDataModelWithPhoneNumber
     {
        Id = (contact.Id ?? Guid.Empty).ToString()
     };

    contactDataModel.Email = contact.Emails()?.PreferredEmail?.SmtpAddress;
    contactDataModel.FirstName = contact.Personal()?.FirstName;
    contactDataModel.LastName = contact.Personal()?.LastName;
    var contactIdentifier = contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Source == "ListManager") ??
         contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault();
    contactDataModel.Identifier = contactIdentifier?.Identifier;
    contactDataModel.IdentifierSource =
    contactIdentifier?.Source;
    contactDataModel.PhoneNumber =
    contact.GetFacet<PhoneNumber>().Number;
    return contactDataModel;
}
```

- create configurator class

```
public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
     var serviceToRemove = serviceCollection
        .Where(service => service.ServiceType == typeof(IListSubscribersMapper))
        .FirstOrDefault();
     serviceCollection.Remove(serviceToRemove);
     serviceCollection.AddTransient<IListSubscribersMapper, ListSubscribersWithPhoneNumberMapper >();
}
```

- register configurator and additional facets in config patch file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
     <services>
        <configurator type=" ContactListExtender.CustomServiceConfigurator, ContactListExtender" />
     </services>
     <settings>
      <!-- Adds the PhoneNumber facet to be loaded  -->
          <setting name="ListManagement.Contacts.FacetsToRead" set:value="ListSubscriptions|Personal|Emails|PhoneNumber" />
     </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Source and more information in Sitecore Documentation here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--extending-the-list-manager-to-show-custom-columns-in-a-contact-list.html